# How do i check if a few variables are defined?

Tags: javascript

ich want to check if my 3 variables are defined but this doesnt work:

```
If (typeof inputServer && inputUser && inputPassword !="undefined") {
        alert("it works!");
    }
```

My debugger says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { "

Please help me :)

greets Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `if` should be lowercase.

Then, you could do it like this:

```
if (inputServer !== undefined && inputUser !== undefined && inputPassword !== undefined) {
    alert("it works!");
}
```

If you wanted to check if they were not `undefined` OR `null` you could do (and this is one of the rare circumstances when using double equality is useful):

```
if (inputServer != null && inputUser != null && inputPassword != null) {
    alert("it works!");
}
```

And lastly, if you wanted to check if they weren't any falsy value (`null`, `undefined`, `false`, `-0`, `+0`, `NaN`, `''`), you could do:

```
if (inputServer && inputUser && inputPassword) {
    alert("it works!");
}
```

**Sidenote**: You don't need to use `typeof` in most normal circumstances -- that is unless `undefined` is actually a variable defined somewhere in your program...

Fortunately, in ECMAScript 5.1 it's not possible to overwrite `window.undefined` http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.1.3

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript is case sensitive language. `if` keyword starts with small `i`.

Additionally, I'd recommend you to use `typeof inputServer !== "undefined"` to check if variable was defined.

**REF:** [Detecting an undefined object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property-in-javascript)

Comment: I would not. Really, who is stupid enough to define undefined?

Comment: @jgillich It's fool-proof solution anyway.

Comment: Sometimes it is better to learn things the hard way. But that's just my humble opinion. :)

Comment: I agree with @jgillich. The clunky `typeof foo !== "undefined"` syntax causes more errors *(due to typing it incorrectly)* than actually redefining `undefined`.

Answer (score 3):

```
if ((inputServer != undefined) && (inputUser != undefined) && (inputPassword != undefined)) {
        alert("it works!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's if(all lower) and not If - and if the vars is not defined it's still gives you an error cause you are asking them - what you can do is (assuming this code runs at global scope as i understand:

```
if(typeof(window.inputServer) != 'undefined' && typeof(window.inputUser) != 'undefined'){

}
```